# Removing stale xrandr entries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr

I recently switched video cards under Kubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and the xrandr command has cached many of the old settings.

```
$ xrandr | grep "connected"
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 2560x1600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y    axis) 641mm x 401mm
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 2560x1600+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4.8 connected 2560x1600+5120+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 641mm x 401mm
DP-4.1.8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

ALL of the disconnected displays are actually variations of the same CONNECTED displays (i.e. I have ALWAYS had the same 3 monitors), but they have been moved from Intel (IGP) to AMD and now currently an NVIDIA GTX-1080.

I would REALLY like to remove the old and extraneous entries.  **Where is this data stored?**  Other than a complete re-install (which I am not keen to do. Removal of old drivers didn't clean this up either) how can I handle this?

I understand why this information persists, but I feel it is actually getting in the way of kscreen(?) or kwin(?) or what ever, because my display layout has become exceptionally unstable.